# CKEDITOR and KCFINDER Upload works, Image Thumbnail Browse fails

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor, kcfinder

Vanilla install of `CKEDITOR` and `KCFINDER` Upload works just fine. I can select an image from my computer and send it to the server. The image pops up fine on the `CKeditor`.

If I try to place an image into `CKeditor` that already exists, the browse option opens `kcfinder` and I can see all the images listed that I have already uploaded.

The problem is that the image thumbnail does not display (see attached photo).  I only see a blank box with the file name listed.

The images and thumbnails are on the server and I can select the blank thumbnail. When the selected image is placed into the `CKeditor` windows, the actual image does properly show up.  It is definitely something about the display of the image insider the `KCfinder` browse.

Anyone have any ideas?  I have tried the removal of the htaccess file from the upload directory and the disabling of the`_check4htaccess` option in the configuration. The problem persists.

[image: Thumbnail does not display]

ADDED CONFIG FILE

```
<?php

/** This file is part of KCFinder project
*
*      @desc Base configuration file
*   @package KCFinder
*   @version 3.12
*    @author Pavel Tzonkov <sunhater@sunhater.com>
* @copyright 2010-2014 KCFinder Project
*   @license http://opensource.org/licenses/GPL-3.0 GPLv3
*   @license http://opensource.org/licenses/LGPL-3.0 LGPLv3
*      @link http://kcfinder.sunhater.com
*/

/* IMPORTANT!!! Do not comment or remove uncommented settings in this file
even if you are using session configuration.
See http://kcfinder.sunhater.com/install for setting descriptions */

$_CONFIG = array(


// GENERAL SETTINGS

'disabled' => true,
'uploadURL' => "https://example.com/library/kcfinder/upload",
'uploadDir' => "",
'theme' => "dark",

'types' => array(

// (F)CKEditor types
    'files'   =>  "",
    'flash'   =>  "swf",
    'images'  =>  "*img",

// TinyMCE types
    'file'    =>  "",
    'media'   =>  "swf flv avi mpg mpeg qt mov wmv asf rm",
    'image'   =>  "*img",
),


// IMAGE SETTINGS

'imageDriversPriority' => "imagick gmagick gd",
'jpegQuality' => 90,
'thumbsDir' => ".thumbs",

'maxImageWidth' => 0,
'maxImageHeight' => 0,

'thumbWidth' => 100,
'thumbHeight' => 100,

'watermark' => "",


// DISABLE / ENABLE SETTINGS

'denyZipDownload' => false,
'denyUpdateCheck' => false,
'denyExtensionRename' => false,


// PERMISSION SETTINGS

'dirPerms' => 0755,
'filePerms' => 0644,

'access' => array(

    'files' => array(
        'upload' => true,
        'delete' => true,
        'copy'   => true,
        'move'   => true,
        'rename' => true
    ),

    'dirs' => array(
        'create' => true,
        'delete' => true,
        'rename' => true
    )
),

'deniedExts' => "exe com msi bat cgi pl php phps phtml php3 php4 php5 php6 
py pyc pyo pcgi pcgi3 pcgi4 pcgi5 pchi6",


// MISC SETTINGS

'filenameChangeChars' => array(/*
    ' ' => "_",
    ':' => "."
*/),

'dirnameChangeChars' => array(/*
    ' ' => "_",
    ':' => "."
*/),

'mime_magic' => "",

'cookieDomain' => "",
'cookiePath' => "",
'cookiePrefix' => 'KCFINDER_',


// THE FOLLOWING SETTINGS CANNOT BE OVERRIDED WITH SESSION SETTINGS

'_normalizeFilenames' => false,
'_check4htaccess' => false,
//'_tinyMCEPath' => "/tiny_mce",

'_sessionVar' => "KCFINDER",
//'_sessionLifetime' => 30,
//'_sessionDir' => "/full/directory/path",
//'_sessionDomain' => ".mysite.com",
//'_sessionPath' => "/my/path",

//'_cssMinCmd' => "java -jar /path/to/yuicompressor.jar --type css 
{file}",
//'_jsMinCmd' => "java -jar /path/to/yuicompressor.jar --type js {file}",

);

?>
```

Comment: show me your `ckfinder/config.php` file

Comment: Updated with the config file.  Only two minimal changes to the vanilla install and that is the uploadURL and theme.

Comment: good see this folder `library/kcfinder/upload` image exists?
`